# check if EditText has more than 2 characters on button click only gets first click value

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I have an activity that user can send an image or a text or both.
I don't want users to send something without an image and an text. It can have an image or only an text but need one.

For text I check if the field has more than 1 character:

```
uploadImageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUploadName);
```

...
click function

```
        bUploadImage.setEnabled(false);

        Bitmap image = null;
        if(hasImage(imageToUpload)) {
            image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageToUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        }
        else{
            if(uploadImageName.length() < 2){ // no image and no text
                bUploadImage.setEnabled(true);
                return;
            }
        }
        new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString());
```

if user type one character and click send button it will work ok, active the button to allow user to add more characters and try again.

The problem is it will not work at the second try, if user type 40 characters, for example, it will enter in the return too.

It only happens if user in the first try add less than 2 characters. the second one will not allow user to send. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks as though you only check the length when there is not an image to upload, so if there is an image to upload it will always upload.

Comment: Remove `else` statement.

Comment: @MikeT yeah, if it has an image it will upload, no problem if it has a text or not. If has no image, it need, at least one character to send only the text.

Comment: @Stanojkovic without else it will force a text always. I want to allow only image or image and text or only text.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, the conditions for sending data are image or text which contains at least one char ?

```
bUploadImage.setEnabled(false);

            Bitmap image = null;

            if(hasImage(imageToUpload) || (uploadImageName.length() > 0) {
             if(hasImage(imageToUpload)){
               image = ((BitmapDrawable) imageToUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
           }

          bUploadImage.setEnabled(true);

    }


            new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString());
```